Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, specified path "/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/config/msp" does not exist or cannot be accessed
In the implementation of multi-machine deployment, after I successfully deployed the network, the chain code can be successfully initialized in the container, and the invoke and query are successful. But when I run it in the virtual machine, I have this title problementer image description here
This is my relevant profile
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "OrdererOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing orderer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OrdererOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Orderer
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs" - See PeerOrgs below for complete description
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "PeerOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing peer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PeerOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org1
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: org1.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "CA"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Uncomment this section to enable the explicit definition of the CA for this
    # organization.  This entry is a Spec.  See "Specs" section below for details.
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # CA:
    #    Hostname: ca # implicitly ca.org1.example.com
    #    Country: US
    #    Province: California
    #    Locality: San Francisco
    #    OrganizationalUnit: Hyperledger Fabric
    #    StreetAddress: address for org # default nil
  Template:
      Count: 1
      # Start: 5
      # Hostname: {{.Prefix}}{{.Index}} # default
      # SANS:
      #   - "{{.Hostname}}.alt.{{.Domain}}"

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Users"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Count: The number of user accounts _in addition_ to Admin
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Users:
      Count: 1

  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org2: See "Org1" for full specification
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org2
    Domain: org2.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 1
    Users:
      Count: 1

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "OrdererOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing orderer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OrdererOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Orderer
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs" - See PeerOrgs below for complete description
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "PeerOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing peer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PeerOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org1
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: org1.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "CA"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Uncomment this section to enable the explicit definition of the CA for this
    # organization.  This entry is a Spec.  See "Specs" section below for details.
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # CA:
    #    Hostname: ca # implicitly ca.org1.example.com
    #    Country: US
    #    Province: California
    #    Locality: San Francisco
    #    OrganizationalUnit: Hyperledger Fabric
    #    StreetAddress: address for org # default nil
  Template:
      Count: 1
      # Start: 5
      # Hostname: {{.Prefix}}{{.Index}} # default
      # SANS:
      #   - "{{.Hostname}}.alt.{{.Domain}}"

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Users"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Count: The number of user accounts _in addition_ to Admin
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Users:
      Count: 1

  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org2: See "Org1" for full specification
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org2
    Domain: org2.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 1
    Users:
      Count: 1

version: '2'

services:
  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    extra_hosts:
      - "orderer.example.com:82.156.214.214"
      - "peer0.org1.example.com:124.70.74.28"
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:123.60.9.71"
      
  ca_orderer:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-orderer
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_CN=ca-orderer
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_HOSTS=ca.orderer.example.com
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/ca:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    container_name: ca_orderer
    extra_hosts:
      - "ca.orderer.example.com:82.156.214.214"
      - "ca.org1.example.com:124.70.74.28"
      - "ca.org2.example.com:123.60.9.71"


version: '2'

services:
  couchdb0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: couchdb0.org1.example.com
    image: couchdb:3.1
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=admin
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=adminpw
    ports:
      - 5984:5984

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=300s
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0.org1.example.com:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=admin
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=adminpw
    depends_on:
      - couchdb0.org1.example.com

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7052:7052
      - 7053:7053
    extra_hosts:
      - "orderer.example.com:82.156.214.214"
      - "peer0.org1.example.com:124.70.74.28"
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:123.60.9.71"
  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./chaincode/go/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-cluster/chaincode/go
      - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
      - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    extra_hosts:
      - "orderer.example.com:82.156.214.214"
      - "peer0.org1.example.com:124.70.74.28"
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:123.60.9.71"


  ca_org1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_CN=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_HOSTS=ca.org1.example.com
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    container_name: ca_org1
    extra_hosts:
      - "orderer.example.com:82.156.214.214"
      - "ca.org1.example.com:124.70.74.28"
      - "ca.org2.example.com:123.60.9.71"



version: '2'

services:
  couchdb0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: couchdb0.org2.example.com
    image: couchdb:3.1
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=admin
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=adminpw
    ports:
      - 5984:5984

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=300s
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0.org2.example.com:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=admin
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=adminpw
    depends_on:
      - couchdb0.org2.example.com

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7052:7052
      - 7053:7053
    extra_hosts:
      - "orderer.example.com:82.156.214.214"
      - "peer0.org1.example.com:124.70.74.28"
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:123.60.9.71"
  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./chaincode/go/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-cluster/chaincode/go
      - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
      - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    extra_hosts:
      - "orderer.example.com:82.156.214.214"
      - "peer0.org1.example.com:124.70.74.28"
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:123.60.9.71"
  

  ca_org2:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org2
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_CN=ca-org2
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_HOSTS=ca.org2.example.com
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    container_name: ca_org2
    extra_hosts:
      - "ca.orderer.example.com:82.156.214.214"
      - "ca.org1.example.com:124.70.74.28"
      - "ca.org2.example.com:123.60.9.71"




I forgot the command for the org2 node. However, the same problem still occurs when running the following command on the terminalenter image description here

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
